# ofstream is replacing the entire file instead of within certain bounds

Tags: c++, ofstream

My program creates 100 'records' of a client inside of a file.
Within the program, a user is allowed to change values of a client at any index between 1-100. 
Whenever I try change the values at a given index, the program doesn't only edit the record within the bounds, but it doesn't keep anything before it. 
Let's say I have a record at index 50, if I try to edit the record at index 1, the record at index 50 won't be there.
I don't know how to fix this problem, but here's the code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct clientData {
    int accountNumber;
    char lastName[15];
    char firstName[10];
    float balance;
};

void initializeFile();
void getClientInfo();
void printAllInfo();
void printUserByIndex(int);

int main() {
    initializeFile();

    getClientInfo();
    getClientInfo();

    cout << "Which index would you like to get the data at?" << endl;
    int userIndex;
    cin >> userIndex;
    printUserByIndex(userIndex);
    printAllInfo();
    return 0;
}

void printAllInfo() {
    ifstream inCredit("credit.dat", ios::in);
    clientData lastClient;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        clientData newClient;
        inCredit.seekg((i - 1) * sizeof(clientData));
        inCredit.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&newClient), sizeof(clientData));
        cout << "Account number: " << newClient.accountNumber << endl;
        cout << "First name: " << newClient.firstName << endl;
        if (newClient.accountNumber != 0
                && lastClient.accountNumber != newClient.accountNumber) {
            cout << "Account number: " << newClient.accountNumber << endl;
            cout << "First name: " << newClient.firstName << endl;
            cout << "Last name: " << newClient.lastName << endl;
            cout << "Account balance: " << newClient.balance << endl;
            lastClient = newClient;
        }
    }
}

void printUserByIndex(int index) {
    ifstream inCredit("credit.dat", ios::in);
    clientData newClient;
    inCredit.seekg((index - 1) * sizeof(clientData));
    inCredit.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&newClient), sizeof(clientData));
    cout << "Account number: " << newClient.accountNumber << endl;
    cout << "First name: " << newClient.firstName << endl;
    cout << "Last name: " << newClient.lastName << endl;
    cout << "Account balance: " << newClient.balance << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void getClientInfo() {
    clientData client1;
    ofstream outCredit1("credit.dat", ios::ate);
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 100!" << endl;
    cin >> client1.accountNumber;
    cout << "Please enter the client's first name" << endl;
    cin >> client1.firstName;
    cout << "Please enter the client's last name" << endl;
    cin >> client1.lastName;
    cout << "Please enter the client's balance name" << endl;
    cin >> client1.balance;
    cout << client1.accountNumber - 1 << endl;
    outCredit1.seekp((client1.accountNumber - 1) * sizeof(clientData));
    outCredit1.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&client1),
            sizeof(clientData));
    outCredit1.close();
}

void initializeFile() {
    ofstream outCredit("credit.dat", ios::out);
    clientData blankClient = { 0, "", "", 0.0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        outCredit.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&blankClient),
                sizeof(clientData));
    }
    outCredit.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, but `outCredit1.write("Y", 1)` means that the next write of the record is off-by-one, so you'll not be able to correctly read it back. Please also add some error-checking, so you can be sure your file operations have succeeded.

Comment: I forgot to edit that out, it should be correct now @RemyLebeau

Comment: You don't need the `seekg()` call in `printAllInfo()` since you are reading the file sequentially (the whole loop in general is questionable, though). But more importantly, why does `getClientInfo()` write a `'Y'` char to the front of each record? That corrupts not only the record being written but also the record that follows it, as you are writing `sizeof(clientData)+1` bytes where `sizeof(clientData)` bytes are needed. Also, no matter what, you need to add the `std::ios::binary` flag to your `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` objects since you are working with structs and not text